# How to call Thread derived class method from run in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, inheritance

Currently I'm not a python programmer, but I'm giving some maintenance to some python code, and I have what's more or less the following:

```
class DerivedThread(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)

  def initStuff():
    print "Hello 2"

  def run(self):
    print "Hello 1"
    self.initStuff()
    print "Hello 3"
```

`initStuff` does not call `print` in truth, just set some variables, I've added this method for organization, there was only `__init__` and `run` before.

The problem is that, once execution reachs `self.initStuff()`, I see no messages following anymore, only `"Hello 1"`, I thought it was some problem with calling derived methods with python, but I don't know what's happening.

What's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I got it, I just needed to pass `self` as argument to `initStuff`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in definition of your `initStuff` method. It requires at least one argument (usually called 'self') in it's definition (you've defined no arguments). Let's see what happens then:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def initStuff(self):
        pass

c = MyClass()
c.initStuff()

TypeError: initStuff() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

So obviously your code fails silently in thread you've defined.

The way to fix the problem is to define `initStuff` method following Python rules.

```
 ...
 def initStuff(self):  #  Here 'self' argument is defined
      pass
```

This kind of method is called **instancemethod** as it's called on behalf of your class instance (and the first argument is an instance object itself that must be explicitly defined).

Read more about classes in [documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#classes).